# update statement conflicted with foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have problem on updating column set as primary key, even I made on update set default

this is my code for creating tables, I set on update set default

```
create table department(
id int default 10 primary key,
name varchar(50)
);

create table employee
(
id int primary key,
dept_id int default 40 foreign key references department(id) on update set default on delete set default,
    name varchar(40)
);
```

after that, I inserted data to the tables

```
insert into department
values
(1,'hr'),
(2,'programming'),
(3,'telesales'),
(4,'database')

insert into employee
values
(1,1,'mohammed'),
(2,2,'magd'),
(3,1,'soha'),
(4,3,'sameh'),
(5,4,'ashraf')
```

but, when I run this code to update the column id

```
update department
set id = 44 where id = 4
```

I get that error

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__employee__dept_i__571DF1D5". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.department", column 'id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

but I do not know where is my fault!

thanks

Comment: So, you've declared the column to have a default value of `40`, which is a value not contained in the `department` table either before or after your update, and you have `on update set default` in the foreign key constraint. What did you *expect* to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in the foreign key constraint, like so:

```
    create table employee
(
id int primary key,
dept_id int default 40 foreign key references department(id) on update cascade on delete set default,
    name varchar(40)
);
```

If there is any update to the `id` column value, `dept_id` also gets updated to follow the changed value.

Comment: I know that it works, but why when I use on update set default, it appear that error

Comment: Think about it. You have a foreign key relation, and you then change the value. How is the linked table to assume that 44 is the same the 4 stored in it, unless you specify that?

Comment: No worries. On that note, you can also use `ON DELETE CASCADE`, so that if a department is removed, the relevant employees are also removed. This will avoid the scenario where you have orphan records in `employee`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `employee` table have `dept_id` column **constraint** with `id` column of `department`. This error is encountered when the primary key of a table is updated but it is referenced by a foreign key from another table and the update specific is set to No action. The No action is the default option.

If this is your case and No action is set on the update operation you can change the foreign-key definition to Cascade

You can try this:

```
ALTER TABLE employee
DROP Constraint FK__employee__dept_i__571DF1D5
GO

ALTER TABLE employee
ADD CONSTRAINT New_FK_Constraint
FOREIGN KEY (dept_id) REFERENCES department (id)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

it's normally to that error to appear, You have a foreign key relation and you then change the value.

Use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in the foreign key constraint

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your table structure, you can run the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE [UserStore] 
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_UserStore_User_UserId

ALTER TABLE [UserIdentity]
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT  FK_UserIdentity_User_UserId

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE  [user] 
SET Id = 10
WHERE Id = 9

UPDATE  [dbo].[UserStore]
SET UserId = 10
WHERE UserId = 9

UPDATE  [dbo].UserIdentity
SET UserId = 10
WHERE UserId = 9

COMMIT TRAN

ALTER TABLE [UserStore] 
CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_UserStore_User_UserId

ALTER TABLE UserIdentity 
CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_UserIdentity_User_UserId
```

Comment: You're a savior.